Load <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.content.raw }} /> not work, Block validation in edit.js
I have a custom component where I want to display data from the post type 'wp_block'.
I can display the data without any problems when I do NOT use ...
<ul>
    {fetchedData.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
            { item.content.raw }
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>

The data looks like this:
<!-- wp:custom-block/section --> <div class="wp-block-custom-block-section custom-block-block h-auto relative"><div class...

It was displayed in the WP editor and frontend.
However, I want to display the rendered data.
For the output, I tried using dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.content.raw }}:
{fetchedData.map((item, index) => (
    <div
        key={index}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.content.raw }}
    />
))}

This does not work because I always receive a block validation error.
I checked the data from the save and post functions, and in the post, the data from item.content.raw is missing in the post body output.
How can I output data like content.raw in editor.js and save.js without encountering validation problems?
